# Undeclared mixin mat-core angular-material-theme for custom-theme.scss

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was finally able to update all npm package dependencies for my angular project. After doing so, I am now left with this error below. When I hover over `mat-core` and `angular-material-theme` in Visual Studio, they show up as undeclared mixins. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
./src/custom-theme.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: no mixin named mat-core
        on line 10 of src/custom-theme.scss
>> @include mat-core();
   ---------^

    at processResult (C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:703:19)
    at C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:809:5
    at C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:54:7)
    at Object.done [as callback] (C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:8069:18)
    at options.error (C:\Users\ch33f\Documents\Projects\WebProjects\royalcompetition\royalcompetition\ClientApp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:294:32)
```

My package.json is below

```
{
  "name": "royal_competition",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:production": "ng build --prod",
    "build:ssr": "ng run royal_competition:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "12.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "11.0.9",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.2.6",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.14.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.0.9",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.3.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
}
```

Here is the custom-theme.scss

```
// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$royal_competition-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$royal_competition-accent: mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$royal_competition-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$royal_competition-theme: mat-light-theme($royal_competition-primary, $royal_competition-accent, $royal_competition-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($royal_competition-theme);
```

Answer (score 10):

The core mixin
Angular Material defines a mixin named core that includes prerequisite styles for common features used by multiple components, such as ripples. The core mixin must be included exactly once for your application, even if you define multiple themes. Including the core mixin multiple times will result in duplicate CSS in your application.

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Angular Material 12, it's now `mat.core()` instead of `mat-core()`.

Same for other includes.

Normally running the Angular Material upgrade command from the CLI should have updated that for you.

Comment: I tried running what I think is an update command. `npm update @angular/material @angular/cdk` or `ng update @angular/material`. I even deleted all node_modules and ran it again and both commands said I was already up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the the official update [guide](https://update.angular.io/) provided by the Angular-Team it should automatically fix the imports and change the names of the mixins/functions you have already in use.

Besides @angular/flex-layout version should be in sync with your Angular version 12 -> 12 (you have flex-layout 11 and Angular 12).